# Boot issues - Windows 8.1 + Samsung 850 Pro SSD

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, ssd

I have an Asus N56VZ and couple of months back I installed the Samsung SSD. All was good until last night when I was shown the "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key" error. 
In my Bios the name of the ssd is gibberish(as the symbols are in different encoding). I tried to use the Windows 8.1 recovory tool and the command prompt, following this post(The one called "the most helpful post")
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/total-identified-windows-installations-0/52359f87-de4a-41dc-b0c3-cc275e1d9fbf
However, when I reach step 4 it fails with "The requested system device cannot be found."
I tried using the automatic windows recovery tool - it says the drive is locked. 
I also tried booting from two ubuntu live cds - they didnt even boot. 
If i try to install from the windows dvd - when I am supposed to select the drive - the list is empty.

I am open to suggestions on how to fix the issue and thanks for taking the time to read the question.

Edit: just found this topic http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2548883/ssd-850-pro-boot-problem.html
Which explains my exact same problem and the reason for it

Comment: If you found a solution, you can post it and explain it in an answer to your own question, it may help people in the future - remember to add more than the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was. The latest firmware update from Samsung was corrupted and the update process failed, leaving the SSD in the state, explained in my question.
I called Samsung's customer services and they redirected me to a company handling this sort of issues. They sent a delivery company to collect my old SSD and then sent me a brand new one.

This was the only way I could find to "fix" the ssd.
Hope that's helpful.